# How to obtain the new values when a new column is added in a dataframe? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the next problem to solve.

i hava a huge dataframe (14 k rows x 1600 columns) consisting of 1 and 0s. I need to obtain the unique new different values when i considered a new column. Meaning, i have the index column and the first column, then if i consider the second column, i need to be able to obtain the 'count' of how many of the rows are different to the first column. Then, consider the third column and obtain the count of the different values to those from 1st and 2nd column and so on. for example the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["S1", "S2", "S3"])
df
```

because i'm not sure how to write the code, i don't know if is easier to get a new row at the end with the count of the new values or transpose the df and obtain a new column with those values.
in any case the output i expect should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [3, 1, 1]]
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["S1", "S2", "S3"])
df_out
```

Here you can see that with just column 1 there are 3 unique index-value pairs, when we considered columns 1 and 2, we have 2 repeated values but 1 new, and when we add the third column we have just 1 new value when compared with 1 and 2...

So, to clarify myself, look the image below.
[image]

I need to obtain that kind of output for the entire dataframe.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't understand how you get (3, 1, 1). Can you explain it in detail, please?

Comment: Sure @Corralien, so, if you look the '1' in column 1, you have 3, then when you considered the second column, at index 0 & 3 there are '1' in both columns, meaning the pair index-value is not unique, but in column 2 index 2, there's a '1' in that's not in column 1, so the count for new values is 1. If we add the third column, there's 1 values present in columns 1 & 2 (index 3) and 1 repeated in index 2 with column 2.. so at the end just the value in index 4 is new, that's why for column 3 the count of new values is 1